# image with hover effect, when you click on in youtube video should pop up in a light box

Tags: html, css, youtube

I'm trying to code an image which turns to different image by hovering over it. 
By clicking on the image an embedded video pops up (in a light box).

I've tried several different things. That's my current code. Hope someone can help me code a lightbox that pops up with an embedded youtube video by hovering over it.
By the way, I'm aiming for something like on this page -> https://www.garyvaynerchuk.com/

thank you already

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease;

}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image2 {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18AgmjVPEqc">
  <img src="http://politsatire.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/playbutton_before.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="http://politsatire.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/playbutton.png" alt="Avatar" class="image2">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Unfortunately both tips didn't really work out. Probably because I do this project with wordpress which doesnt get along very well with JavaScript or jquery. I solved it now by using the plugin "easy fancy box" and added following code to my previous code.   <a class="fancybox-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TrRLIlp35Uk">

Answer (score 0):

HTML & CSS are not enough to use modals, you need Javascript too in order to handle all related events.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
 /* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You need to adapt this example to your needs.

Original code from: **https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp**

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap modal, you can achieve something like this:

`-`http://jsfiddle.net/julysfx/ysqhswxc